# Smart way to retrieve a Customer Id from a Campaign Response

Tags: dynamics-crm-2011

I am retrieving the customer id from CRM 2011.
I am working with the Campaign Response Entity, but it is something that applies with any other Entity containing a Customer lookup.

The only way I found so far is this one:

```
var customerGuid =
    ((EntityReference)
        ((EntityCollection) ebCampaignResponse.Entity.Attributes["customer"]).Entities[0]
            .Attributes["partyid"]).Id;
```

I think it is way too complicate and that I am missing something. Is there any better way to do it?

IMPROVED CODE:

```
var customerGuid = Guid.Empty;
EntityCollection customer = null;
if (ebCampaignResponse.Entity != null && ebCampaign.Entity.Contains("customer")) 
    customer = (EntityCollection) ebCampaignResponse.Entity.Attributes["customer"];

if(customer != null && customer.Entities != null && customer.Entities[0] != null)
    customerGuid = ((EntityReference)(customer.Entities[0]
            .Attributes["partyid"])).Id;
```

Answer (score 2):

Your code is prone to errors if the customer attribute is null; though the way you are retrieving it is correct but a more cleaner way I would prefer this to be done is as follows

```
var customer = ebCampaignResponse.Entity.GetAttributeValue<EntityCollection>("customer").Entities.FirstOrDefault();
if(customer != null) {
var customerGuid = customer.GetAttributeValue<EntityReference>("partyid").Id;
}
```

PS I doubt there is an attribute called `customer` in the response, I think it should be `customers`. Also, the above code that I included might also throw errors, all I did is formatted your code and showed you a neater way to go about it.

OR (if you don't like the first approach)

```
var customer = ebCampaignResponse.Entity.GetAttributeValue<EntityCollection>("customer").Entities.FirstOrDefault();
if(customer == null) return;
var customerGuid = customer.GetAttributeValue<EntityReference>("partyid").Id;
```

Comment: You declare Guid inside an if statement, Entity Collection has no FirstOrDefault and no GetAttributeValue methods

Comment: This if is gonna contain your entire logic, I mean what's the point in processing further if at first place your customer is not present. This all depends on what you are trying to do. As I said, this is just a formatted version of you code. For the EntityCollection, sorry bout that I missed `Entities` keyword there. The code has been corrected now.

Comment: That did not help when the customer was empty. I still got an error saying that the given key was not present in the dictionary. I have updated the code to include that possibility.

Comment: buddy, Stack overflow is there to help you find a way out and not to code for you. These errors are the most common errors and the most descriptive errors you would get. `KeyNotFoundException` means the customer is not present, so modify the code accordingly and handle this situation in your code.